# What happened to the overseas wealth of the Holocaust Jews?

Tags: jews, holocaust, banking

Hitler confiscated the wealth of Jews in his conquered territories. But what happened to the overseas wealth of the Holocaust Jews? Were they swallowed conveniently by foreign banks/countries pretending to help but could not help? Were they honorably returned to the descendants of the victims? It will be interesting to know which country or bank was most honorable in handling their troubled clients' money.

Comment: You could start off by reading Wikipedia's articles on the Claims Conference and about the [Swiss banks and money of Jewish victims of Nazi persecution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Jewish_Congress_lawsuit_against_Swiss_banks). Then, using the sources cited in those articles and your favorite search engine, dig deeper. I am sure there are some scholarly works out there already that discuss your questions.

Comment: Whole books can be written about this question. IMO you need to narrow it down to the fate of a particular family fortune, say.

Comment: Of the German, Austrian and Czech Jews who had foreign bank accounts (investors, bankers, importers, etc), *most of them had fled the country by 1939*. The Jews who remained within those countries were predominantly poor, as were most of the Jews living in Belarus, the Ukraine and much of Poland. While there were some wealthy Jews in Romania and Greece, my guess is that you probably want to focus on Jews in Hungary, France and the Netherlands, where more of them were engaged in the finance sector. Perhaps Hungary in particular, where they comprised a large part of the banking class.